# After restarting, macOS Catalina on VMWare fails to boot

Tags: vmware, macos-catalina

Some time ago I installed [macOS Catalina on VMWare](https://techsviewer.com/how-to-install-macos-10-15-catalina-on-vmware-on-windows-pc/) to be able to build for iOS. This has worked perfectly. At one time, I snapshotted the vm before an OS Update. The update went fine and I have continued to use it since, but recently the OS crashed and failed to boot afterwards. Reverting to the snapshot was my only go-to option, but unlike the first time, I cannot restart that snapshot anymore - it fails with the same error message on bootup. This is a bit mysterious, given that I was able to restart it initially after updating it. There must be some kind of state here that is outside of the snapshot, it seems. Could it be that upgrading VMWare bricks the VM?

How can I find out what causes the OS to fail to start? Inspecting `vmware.log` in the vm folder does not reveal much, AFAIK. This is the last thing it prints:

```
2020-03-25T13:24:21.530+01:00| vcpu-0| I125: AHCI-VMM: sata0:29: PxSCTL.DET already 0. Ignoring write 0.
2020-03-25T13:24:21.987+01:00| vcpu-0| I125: Guest: Status upon boot failure: No Media
2020-03-25T13:24:22.040+01:00| vcpu-0| I125: Guest: About to do EFI boot: EFI VMware Virtual SATA Hard Drive (0.0)
```

[Full output from `vmware.log`](https://www.jottacloud.com/s/002f3c413e9e3184fea8897ea3df1b08d1a)

[image: problem]

Comment: It's a kernel panic alright, apparently caused by a crashing virtual AHCI driver in VMWare. Reinstalling VMWare won't delete your VM, but it could solve your problem. Best clean re-install it. I were you, I'd use Revo Uninstaller to completely rid your PC of VMWare Workstation, then install from an up-to-date installer directly from the editor's website. If you instruct Revo not to delete your VMs, it'll leave them alone. You can import them later once your re-installed VMWare Workstation.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the use of macOS on non-Apple hardware is a legal grey area and as a result "Hackintosh" questions have been deemed [off-topic](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/1471/are-hackintosh-questions-allowed).

Answer (score -1):

The issue seems to be related to the "Mac OS" boot entry.  If you set it to SATA and change the first boot item to be the SATA DISK not the boot.efi entry, it should work.

EDIT: You need to go into the EFI setup as it boots - you probably need to check the “enter setup on next boot” option to get there.  Apparently I can’t comment so I can’t directly reply to your question.

Comment: Sorry, but I have absolutely no idea how to do that. There is no boot entry in VMWare... Do you mean I have to change a boot entry "inside" of the guest OS? Tried googling this to no avail: https://www.google.com/search?q=mac+boot.efi&oq=mac+boot.efi